# Javascript Pop Menu (Twitter Style). Add Check in & Check out Calendar in the form

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, xhtml

I would like to know, how I can add Check in And Check out date Calendar, in the Twitter styled sign pop Menu (`http://aext.net/example/twitterlogin/#`). I used this menu in Travel website, that's why I need Check in and Check out dates.

Comment: We have implemented with all the codes together, we are unable to get the dates from Callender... May be it conflicts with other coding values....

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it has nothing with php at all, it's all about plain javascript(jquery). There are seldom jquery calendar plugins, like http://www.overset.com/2008/05/12/multiday-calendar-datepicker-jquery-plugin/ or others. I can't guess what are you expecting from the calendar, but all the standart "functions" are surely included in the most of them.The choice of plugin is on you. Cheers